# How can I update item in express js router after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make a post request after 1 hour to update a mongoose schema. Because i have a task where i need to make a bolean "livestream: false" to be the opposite "livestream: true" in 1 hour or a certaine time.

Any tips ?

Comment: you can create a cronjob for that

Answer (score 1):

In a continuously available node.js server, you can use `setTimeout()` to run some code in one hour.

```
// run some function in 1 hour
setTimeout(function() {
    // put your code here
    console.log("one hour has passed");
}, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

If you want to run the code at some specific time in the future, then you would need to calculate how many ms there are between now and that time in the future and do a `setTimeout()` for that many ms.  You can use `Date.now()` to get the current time and you can construct Date objects with future dates/times in them to get the time in the future and then subtract the two to see how much time there is between now and that future time/date.